# Jquery execute action based on element's parent tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I have the following:

```
<ul class="head clearfix">\
    <li class=""><strong><a href="/firmy" class="menuTabs">Katalog firm <span>(3516)</span></a></strong></li>
    <li class=""><a href="/produkty" class="menuTabs">Katalog produktów <span>(23752)</span></a></li>
    <li class=""><a href="/uslugi" class="menuTabs">Katalog uslug <span>(81)</span></a></li>
    <li class="last"><a href="/szkolenia" class="menuTabs">Katalog szkolen <span>(529)</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

I need to execute a mouseover effect only on links that do NOT have `<strong>` tag as parent. So in the example above I would skip "Katalog firm" link since that one has a  tag as parent.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just filter out the elements that has a parent with the strong tag from the selector and attach the mouse events :

```
​$('ul.head li a')​.filter(function() {
    return !$(this).parent().is('strong');
}).on('mouseenter', function() {
    $(this).css('color','green');
});​
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/35sZx/)

Answer (score 2):

your css selector would be

```
ul.header > li > a.menuTabs:hover
```

to define the hover effect

if you need some jquery functionallity, you can use

```
$('ul.header > li > a.menuTabs')
```

to get those elements

Answer (score 1):

This could be defined in CSS only by using the direct child selector `>`

```
ul.head > li > a.menuTabs:hover 
{
   /* hover style */
}
```

You can use the same selector in jquery

```
$('ul.head > li > a.menuTabs')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.head').on('click', 'li > a', function(evt) {
    //do something
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest, as an alternative to using a more specific selector (probably the better option in most cases) checking the parent element in the mouseover event:

```
$('a').on('mouseover', function(e){
    var that = this;
    if ($(that).parent().is('strong')) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        // do stuff.
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.head > li > .menuTabs').mouseover(fucnction () {
  // code here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use like this.

```
ul li>a:hover
{
background-color:black;
}​
```